# Vector3.hh not found on Gazebo9

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Gazebo Community,

I am currently trying to run the Wil Selby ROS-quadrotor simulator, but I cant get through. (https://github.com/wilselby/ROS_quadrotor_simulator)

actually I am getting an error which says:

```
fatal error: gazebo/math/Vector3.hh: No such file or directory
 #include <gazebo/math/Vector3.hh>
```

is there any possibility to get that Vector3.hh file into my gazebo/math path? I am pretty new to ROS and Gazebo and appreciate any help! Thanks alot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21872/vector3.hh-not-found-on-gazebo9/) by [cluue](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8256/cluue/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo math has been deprecated since Gazebo 8, it looks like your package is meant to be used with earlier versions. You'll need to edit the source code to use Ignition math instead. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/bd1cdea8fa3d71d6afcdaa83c9b01891d5f72e71/Migration.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)'s a full list of functions to be migrated.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cluue](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8256/cluue/) on 2019-02-06**:
Thats a good hint. Just to make sure, do I need to modify the source code of my gazebo version? Is there a chance for you to explain that a bit more detailled, as I mentioned I'm kinda new to all this.

Thanks alot anyways for your advice!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-02-06**:
You'll need to change the source code of the `ROS_quadrotor_simulator`, or downgrade to Gazebo 7.